# Adding new content to a session

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, session

I have an asp.net dropdown list and an asp.net gridview control.
    On changing the dropdownlist element , a new row is fetched from the database.

I am storing this in a session .Next time there is a change in the dropdownlist element , there will
be a new row fetched from the database and I would like to add that row too , to the session.

I have the dropdownlist_selectedIndexchanged event below :

```
protected void ddlClient_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    int x = int.Parse(ddlClient.SelectedValue);

    DataSet ds = GetRowFromDatabase( x);
    Session["old"] = ds;
    ((DataSet)Session["old"]).Merge(ds);

    gridview.DataSource = Session["old"] ;
    gridview.DataBind();

}
```

I cannot figure out how to keep appending my rows in the session variable, each time my dropdownlist changes ?

Comment: So this is really a problem with the `Merge`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void ddlClient_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    int x = int.Parse(ddlClient.SelectedValue);

    DataSet ds = GetRowFromDatabase( x);

    //the first time initialize the session variable
    if(Session["old"] == null)
    {
        Session["old"] = ds;
    }
    else
    { 
        ((DataSet)Session["old"]).Merge(ds);
    }

    gridview.DataSource = Session["old"] ;
    gridview.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: @SqlSamurai keep in mind that each time you assign or use a session["variable"] a serialization is happening and if the the data is big this can affect performance, you can use intermediate variables to access the session variable once and the updated it when need just once also